# action sequence (objective C) iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm having a issue figuring out how to do make sequential actions occur.

Broken down to its simplest form what I'm trying to do is make image1 grow 25% larger and only upon completion of this action will a sound play.

I can make the image grow, I can make the sound play, no problem, but I cannot figure out how to make the sound play ONLY after the image has grown it's 25 percent.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you growing the image?  can you provide any code? are you animating the growth of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you are using an animation to resize the image/view? If so you

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(resizeFinished:finished:context:)];
// Resize the view/image here
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and then in the selector you can play the sound

```
- (void)resizeFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context;
{
    // Play the sound here
}
```

You can also implement the callback delegate

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use core animation, you can run your continuation logic in a completion block (iOS 4). Or you can register a callback on `setAnimationDidStopSelector`. Take a look [here](http://objcolumnist.com/2010/09/19/core-animation-using-blocks/) for details.